# Android User Specific Push Notifications

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification

I need some advice on sending pus notifications to my android app built in android studio. I have done a lot of research on the subject but it seems that all the examples, tutorials etc sends one notification to multiple users (similar to a news app that sends a notification about a new article to all of its readers) using GCM, pushbots etc.

What I am trying to achieve is to send a specific account notification to a specific user (similar to a facebook push notification when someone writes on your wall or the bank sending a push notification when a transaction occurs on your account).

The backend data will be on SQL server and as data comes in to the server, notifications needs to be sent to the associated user.

I am not sure if the processing of this happens on the server and then just pushes the notification to the users android device or if there is a service running on the android device which runs in the background and periodically checks for changes in the data and then gives a notification when it detects a change in the data based on certain conditions (more like a pull notification if you will as the android device actually pulls from the server).

Any advice as to where I can start and do more research regarding this will be much appreciated.

Comment: read more about FCM, the new GCM : https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/